# How to get src from object to my Vue.js image

Tags: vue.js

Now I am trying to get src from object to my vue.js component

```
export const Quizzes = [
  {
    firstWord: "happy",
    secondWord: "srećan",
    imageSrc: "../assets/happy--women.jpg",
  },
]
```

my data.js file looks like this

and how can i use this in my Vue.js component

```
<img class="happy-women" src="../assets/earth.jpg" alt="Quiz Image" />
```

here instead of src link

Comment: What's the vue version ? and what's the build tool vue cli or vite?

Comment: Can you try to use require function like this   :src="require('../assets/earth.jpg')"

Comment: I am using Vite

Comment: Please share the whole code to make the picture clear

Comment: Not sure how `Quizzes` is added to your component but say you have it as an array in your component, you bind the `<img>` src like so: `<img :src="Quizzes[i].imageSrc">`.  The index of the array can be from a `v-for` directive or some other logic inside your component

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, You just simply want to bind the object `imageSrc` property value in the `src` attribute of `img` element in the template ? If Yes, Here you go **:**

```
<img v-for="(quiz, index) in Quizzes"
  :key="index"
  :class="`${quiz.firstWord}-${quiz.secondWord}`"
  :src="quiz.imageSrc"
  alt="Quiz Image" />
```